# How can I select the first set of elements within a list?

Tags: f#

How can I select the first set of elements within a list via index?

I am trying to think functional even though the code below is somewhat imperative when attempting to retrieve the first two cards.

```
let deal (deck: Card list) =
// ------------------------------------
//  let card1 = deck |> Seq.item 0 // Rewrite this logic of getting first two cards
//  let card2 = deck |> Seq.item 1
// ------------------------------------
    let hand = [<get first two elements in deck>]
    let deckUsed = deck |> Seq.except [card1; card2;]
    (card1, card2, deckUsed);;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
let deal =
    function
    |card1::card2::deckUsed -> Some (card1, card2), deckUsed
    |_ -> None, []
```

You can retrieve the results:

```
let hand, newDeck = deal deck
    match hand with
    |Some (card1, card2) -> // do something with the cards
    |None -> // do something if no cards
```

I've just used a simple option type but you might want to use a more descriptive union case to handle dealing from a deck with cards available and trying to deal from an empty deck.

Edit:  I took the deck list out of the option type because you can always map an empty deck back to an empty deck, that could potentially be handy in certain use cases.

Comment: Thanks InnerLight. I'm struggling with the client call though: let Some(card1, card2), remaining = deal (shuffle deck);;

Comment: @ScottNimrod Hope that update helps. I'm not really sure how you want to handle the case of no cards but I'm trying to avoid exceptions and let the success/failure be handled by the option type.

Answer (score 2):

You could use pattern matching:

```
let card1 :: card2 :: unused = deck
```

Note that this fails for `deck`s with less than two cards, as does indexing.